How to fit a GLMM with multiple levels of nesting
I have some data I am struggling to process at the moment. I have landed on using generalized linear mixed models (GLMMs), but I am having a very hard time wrapping my head around it.
I have a large dataset which is composed of concentration measurements of a specific toxin. These measurements have been made in all three types of tissue in my organism (an oyster: Gut, Gill, 'Everything else'). The measurements are not normally distributed. For example, 30 oysters were collected from two different sites in my sample area. Another 30 were collected at a second time of year. I have taken this as being Individual nested in Site nested in Season.
I am trying to see if the Season, Site, or Tissue type have any effect on the concentration measurement.
The hypothesis is that season and tissue certainly will, and I believe that site will too. So, I am trying to construct a model to show this, but I'm coming up totally blank. I assume that to ascertain the effect of season, I need to try and compare the same tissue taken from the same site in two different seasons.
To figure out the effect of site, I need to compare the same tissue from the same season across different sites. To figure the effect of tissue, I need to compare different tissues from the same site and season.
I am unsure of where to go from there, though.
The R code I have is:
glmer(BoxCox ~ 1 + Tissue + Site + Season + (1 | Site) + (1 | Season), data = data, control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))

Anyone got any ideas?

Welcome to SO!  First, the model above doesn't have individual as a random effect, which is needed since each individual has 3 data points, 1 for each tissue.  Second, since you have just 2 sites and 2 seasons, and you are interested in differences between sites and seasons, you don't want those as random effects.  Third, if the data are continuous numeric data you'll want to use lmer()

How is toxin measured in this context? Is it a proportion? A count (e.g. mL of toxin)?
